# Privileged mode vs non usernamespace in docker containers

Tags: linux, docker

From what I know docker doesn't use `user namespaces` by default. So, the user `X(uid=1001)` in container is the same user in host system: `X(uid=1001)`.

When I enable `user namespace` support in docker I see different:

**with usernamepsace enabled:**

```
$ docker run ubuntu sleep 1000
htop returns for `sleep` `uid=165536`
```

**with usernamepsace disabled:**

```
$ docker run ubuntu sleep 1000
htop returns for `sleep` `uid=0`
```

So, we see difference. The process run with usernamespace disabled is ran as root. 
But, why:

`docker run -it ubuntu bash`
`<Try to mount, for example /dev/sda`. <- It is impossible because that container doesn't see /dev/sda/

Output for `ls /dev/`:

```
console  core  fd  full  fuse  mqueue  null  ptmx  pts  random  shm  stderr  stdin  stdout  tty  urandom  zero
```

Why it doesn't see all devices though `bash` is a root? **This is the same root as host root beacause there is no usernamepsace.**

When I run docker in privileged mode `ls /dev/` outputs all, why?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.